# How to find roots to this very complicated nonlinear equation? What nonlinear solver can I use?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find roots for the following equation in $s$ (What nonlinear solver can I use?):
$$\frac{\dfrac{0.64\left(270\left(\left(0.28s\right)+0.42\right)-108\right)}{\left(1-e^{-0.154\left(270\left(\left(0.28s\right)+0.42\right)-108\right)}\right)}}{\left(\dfrac{0.64\left(270\left(\left(0.28s\right)+0.42\right)-108\right)}{\left(1-e^{-0.154\left(270\left(\left(0.28s\right)+0.42\right)-108\right)}\right)}+\dfrac{4.2}{0.1}\right)}=0$$

Comment: Hint: Try to simplify it first. There are terms that could cancel.

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

If you look closely, the fraction can only be $0$ for the value of $s$ that annihilates the numerator of the numerator (which is an easy-to-find rational number). Unfortunately, that value is outside the domain, because it annihilates some denominator as well (the ones in the form $1-e^{\text{stuff}}$).

Answer (score 1):

The fraction can only be zero if the numerator of the numerator is zero. The solution is can be obtained through simplification: $0.64(270(0.28s+0.42)-108)=0\Rightarrow 270(0.28s+0.42)=108\Rightarrow 0.28s=-0.02\Rightarrow s=-1/14$. However, the second denominator is zero at this value, so the answer is that there exist **no** such solutions for **s**.

Comment: What about the other two denominators?

Comment: Nonsense. There are exactly four denominators: $$0.1\\ 1-e^{-0.154(270(0.28s+0.42)-108)}\qquad\text{twice}\\ \frac{0.64(270(0.28s+0.42)-108)}{1-e^{-0.154(270(0.28s+42)-108)}}+\frac{0.42}{0.1}$$

Comment: I am uninterested in the demeanour that led you to being wrong.

Comment: Your answer is still false, though.

Comment: Ok whatever. Fixed it. Answering this question was somewhat pointless but I did so anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a "non-linear solver" as per your question statement. Algebra is sufficient in this case.

Let your expression be called $f$. In addition, let:

$x=270((0.28s)+0.42)-108)$

$y=0.64x$

$z=1-e^{-0.154x}$

$f=(\frac{y}{z}) (\frac{(0.1)z}{(0.1)y+(0.42)(z)})=0$

$\frac{(0.1)y}{(0.1)y+(0.42)(z)}=0 $

$0.1(y)=0$

$0.1(0.64(x))=0$

$0.1(0.64(270((0.28s)+0.42)-108))=0$

The above you can solve for s, to get:

$$s \approx-0.07142\dots $$

You should substitute this value back in $f$ and see if you get a value close to zero or not. It is possible I made a mistake.

If you are not interested in the Algebra, you can easily plot the equation to get the root using any plotting software.